# Windows Store Apps: How Can I Add More Controls to My Listview

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm beginner at developing windows phone 8 and windows store apps with C# and XAML.

Here is my question mark; I want to make a news app to windows 8 store. In this app, I use web api to get the news, articles, authors, games scores etc.

We all know, there are templates. I tried to understand and use GridApp Template but I couldn't get the result.

I see only one gridview and there is listview below it. I know gridview get the template from standardstyles folder but my question is; For example, I want to get my first 10 news from my news web api and use it with Standard250x250ItemTemplate with one control and next to it, I want to use my games scores web api and want to use Standard500x130ItemTemplate template and goes like this.. And this must be scroolable with listview right ? How can I add controls like this.

Shortly;

```
Latest News              Games Scores                 Economy News             ..
(from web service)       (from another web service)   (from another web service)..
___________________________________________________________________________________________
-News One                -Game 1                      -Economy 1
-News Two                -Game 2                      -Economy 2
-News Three              -Game 3                      -Economy 3
-News Four               -Game 4                      -Economy 4
.                        .                            .
.                        .                            .
.                        .                            .
___________________________________________________________________________________________
```

And this all must be scrollable.. I do not ask for use mvvm and try to bind gridview template it will handle it. No, my web api, does not support that structure. I need to make new request to get the related news for everycontrol.

I hope you understand me. I need your helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question and my understanding, you need a GridView template with each group items using a different template form the other. Also for every header you have needs to get data from a different web service. If all this assumptions are right then.

The soln will work for MVVM/Code behind

1. You need to create an observable collection list which binds to the gridview template with headers as "Latest, Games, Economy....". Now you need a class with assuming three fields Title, NewsDescription and Template. The [link](http://win8template5.codeplex.com/) for implementing a custom template.
2. Now suppose you have 3 methods of calling and getting the data from web service. Call the each one by one, and when you get back data, populate the obser. coll. list. In case of code behind, assign the gridview datasource to the list. Do this for all the three methods.

In case you still have doubts, comment on this post, I will reply back

Check out this [link1](http://win8template15.codeplex.com/) as well.

Comment: I'm trying now, I will write here again. Thanks.

Comment: Hi my friend.Actually, I need something like this; If i want to use flipview(you know like a gallery), and near it I want to get my other news as gridview..How can i do that?When i try to that, flipview and gridview are overlapping. You got it mate ? They stay overlap. How can I say to my gridview that; "go and place yourself after flipview, go and stay near it." And goes like this.. I will put a few more like this side by side. Plese help me about this.. Thanks.

Comment: Don't tell me use grid.rowdefinitons and columndefinitons, cuz, my gridview fills with 10 news sometimes with 5 news. It changes. The placement of controls must be set automatically. waiting your answer. thanks

Comment: Hi...Just share the code with me and I can then have a look at it.

Comment: Can you give me your hangout or something else.. code is long and not good i know that.. But I need your help. please..